# MethodNotAllowedHttpException : Calling POST method using Ajax Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-post, laravel-5

I am trying to make an ajax call to a Laravel post method. But I get **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**. One of the possible issue can be mismatch of request type in ajax call and routes controller but that is not the case.

Using Postman, I can confirm that the Post route is working fine. That leaves me an option to focus on AJAX call.

## Issue # 1

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/test', 'HomePageController@test');
```

**custom.js**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
 });
```

and then,

```
$('#teacher-save-submit').click(function(){
    
  var fname = $('#first_name').val();
  var lname = $('#last_name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var passkey = $('#passkey').val();
    
  $.ajax(function(){        
    type:"POST",
    url:"/test",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){
      console.log("success");
      $('#sbt-result').html(data);
     }
   });
});
```

**#Issue # 2**

In console, it shows **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :** at url:"/test"

It would be awesome If you people can share your experiences.

Thanks.

## EDIT

This is what specific error I get. I think that is searching for some GET methods not Posts[image: error_produced]

Comment: Try posting the CSRF token in data in your ajax `data: { '_token': token},` . Where `token = '{{ csrf_token() }}'`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Route::post('test', 'HomePageController@test');
```

js:

```
url:"{{url('test')}}",
```

and prevent the default click event

```
  $('#teacher-save-submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //ajax call
```

Comment: I generally use `{{action('Controller@method')}}`, however, it still worked in my project when I specified the URL as he did for my particular request.

Comment: @madalin, I've edited the post. Check the screenshot. I think it's sending a get request.

Comment: @NaumanZafar you aren't doing a ajax call at all you are doing a page redirect see my updated answer

Comment: @AndrewNolan . I also checked that but doesn't work for me. Can you please see the screenshot. I think laravel is looking for a Get Request

Comment: @Nauman Zafar, it was more in relation to this answer. I wasn't sure if your url would work.I have a few ajax request in my project and I tried it out how you declared the url and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have forgotten put the "meta" tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```